# 'make' compile command when there is files with the same name, but different extensions

Tags: makefile

We usually use 'make' for compiling a single source file with a proper compiler by ...

```
make (file_name_with_no_extension)
```

For example, the way to use 'make' for compiling 'abc.cpp' is

```
make abc
```

not

```
make abc.cpp
```

(Below one should print the message "Nothing to be done for abc.cpp")

So when there are two files in the same directory, for example "abc.c" and "abc.cpp",

```
make abc
```

will always, and only compile "abc.c"(by some default orders? I don't know).

For the cases like this, is there a way to build the cpp file with 'make'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So when there are two files in the same directory, for example "abc.c" and "abc.cpp", `make abc` will always, and only compile "abc.c"(by some default orders? I don't know).

Correct, you can see the order with which the builtin rules are defined with `make -p -f /dev/null`, `%: %.c` is the very first rule for direct compilation from a single source so it has priority.

One way to override this from the command line is to clear the `.SUFFIXES` that make recognises and define your own as follows:

```
make --eval=.SUFFIXES: --eval=.SUFFIXES:.cpp abc
```

Comment: "make --eval='.SUFFIXES:' --eval='.SUFFIXES:.cpp' abc" also compiles abc.c only, although I don't know why and the principles of your commands.

Comment: It works for me in a directory with only `abc.c` and `abc.cpp`, are you absolutely sure you don't have a `Makefile` in the same directory? What version of Make are you using (`make -v`)?

Comment: Just abc.c and abc.cpp in the directory, no makefile. GNU Make 3.82.90 i686-pc-mingw32

Comment: @user3498780 I didn't realise you were on windows, it turns out the quotes are to blame, but they can be removed for this example anyway, try now.

Comment: But it seems now to just overwrite the output file of each they generated(same filename reads to "abc.exe"). Is there a  way to change the output file's name without makefile?

Comment: @user3498780 That's not going to be possible without further `eval` shenanigans, which will just end up writing rules and recipes that would be better off in a file anyway. The builtin rules only work when there is a direct relationship between the executable and the source filenames, if you want to have a differently named executable and still rely on using implicit rules and recipes, then you need to change the name of the source file to match it (which incidentally would make this entire answer pointless).

Answer (score 0):

This "trick" only works because it uses [built-in rules that exist in make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html) - execute `make -p` to get an overview of all built ins in your version of make. You'll also see why the .c file "wins" :)

But having two distinct files whose object file names and default executable file names are identical looks like a pretty bad idea to me, so I would rename one of both files.